# I need to automate this Excel file the best I can

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an Excel sheet that I created. For this sheet it pulls in a data feed on two of the sheets. The data feed has a parameter which I populate from a Drop Down that is fed off of another sheet. I'm trying to automate this process. I want to be able to have the file run through each one of the ID's (the parameter), run the data feed, save the excel sheet, run the next ID save and so on until it goes through the list. Can someone please please help me with this? I'm new to VBA.

Comment: Probably need a bit more information to do anything with this.  Seems like you could very easily just record a macro and take that as your starting point.

Comment: Im so bad with excel I dont know where to begin.

Comment: Click on the arrow on the upperleft of an answer to accept it. Go back to your past questions and accept answers, please.

Comment: Is "data feed" a query table?  Does the query table have a parameter that points to a cell?  Does that cell have Data Validation?  Is the source list of that data validation on a different sheet?

Answer (score 0):

1) you need a list of your IDs.  I like Named Ranges, so mine is named **ID_List**

2) Loop thru your list

```
dim r as range
for each r in [ID_List]
    'do yer stuff here
    'what needs to be done with the value **r.value**???

    'how do you want to save the file each time???
next
```

Need some specific answers!